# Router to WIFI Client to Router (New solution for distance when repeater doesnt help)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, repeater

Ethernet to TL-WR340G with WIFI enabled
Using TL-WA500 tried repeater mode which was not good enough and had password problems (could not connect if using either ASCII or Normal password in one way then in repeater worked other way) and also could not forward (repeat) WPA/WPA2 security.

So since this repeater can also be as client, I made it as client and used another router (*TL-WR740N*) to get from wire connection from that client and all was working for a little bit.

- Every machine is set up to be auto DHCP.

  1st when setting up client mode I found it working after doing reset.

  Then after some tens of minutes internet stopped working.

  When I removed WiFi client then all went back to normal.

#### Where is the problem and how to make this work?

Ethernet->

```
TL-WR340G(AutoDHCP) ==> wifi ==> TL-WA500 
TL-WA500 wifi client mode(AutoDHCP) ==> wire ==> TL-WR740N
TL-WR740N router mode (AutoDHCP) ==> Wifi My Computer
```

In other words:

```
TL-WR340G ) ) ) ) TL-WA500 ===== TL-WR740N ) ) ) ) PC1

) ) WiFi
=== Wire
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, but basic rules apply :

If you are relaying, then no routing is wanted, neither DHCP servicing. Only one device (usually your internet gateway) has to route and serve DHCP, **on a single subnet**. Otherwise you create an unpredictable IP assignment, plus a misconfigured topology that leads to routing and NAT problems.

If too many network interfaces are connected as leaf in a tree of ethernet segments, then the trunk interface (uplink) of a cheap equipment might not handle well the too many MAC addresses is has in its table on a single link, after a few minutes / ARP requests.